# How can I play the next video when my current video is finish using java script?

Tags: javascript

Here i got the success to play the video according to current time but when unable to retrieve the next video after the finishing of current video according to current time. Here startat attribue in source tag is the starting time of that video.

HTML

```
<video id="media-video" width="600" height="300">                   
    <source class="active" src="marimatrubhasha.mp4" id="videosource1" type="video/mp4" startat="00:00:00" endat="00:04:07" name="Gujarati Bhasha" description="This is Gujarati Video">                    
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource2" type="video/mp4" startat="00:04:07" endat="00:19:06" name="PHP Video 00:04:07" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource3" type="video/mp4" startat="00:19:06" endat="00:34:05" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                   
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource4" type="video/mp4" startat="00:34:05" endat="00:49:04" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                   
    <source class="active" src="marimatrubhasha.mp4" id="videosource5" type="video/mp4" startat="00:49:04" endat="00:53:11" name="Gujarati Bhasha" description="This is Gujarati Video">                    
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource6" type="video/mp4" startat="00:53:11" endat="01:08:10" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                   
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource7" type="video/mp4" startat="01:08:10" endat="01:23:09" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                   
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource8" type="video/mp4" startat="01:23:09" endat="01:38:08" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                   
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource9" type="video/mp4" startat="01:38:08" endat="01:53:07" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                   
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource10" type="video/mp4" startat="01:53:07" endat="02:08:06" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource11" type="video/mp4" startat="02:08:06" endat="02:23:05" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource12" type="video/mp4" startat="02:23:05" endat="02:38:04" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource13" type="video/mp4" startat="02:38:04" endat="02:53:03" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource14" type="video/mp4" startat="02:53:03" endat="03:08:02" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource15" type="video/mp4" startat="03:08:02" endat="03:23:01" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource16" type="video/mp4" startat="03:23:01" endat="03:38:00" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource17" type="video/mp4" startat="03:38:00" endat="03:52:59" name="3.38 PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video to be played on 3.38">                    
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource18" type="video/mp4" startat="03:52:59" endat="04:07:58" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource19" type="video/mp4" startat="04:07:58" endat="04:22:57" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource20" type="video/mp4" startat="04:22:57" endat="04:37:56" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource21" type="video/mp4" startat="04:37:56" endat="04:52:55" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource22" type="video/mp4" startat="04:52:55" endat="05:07:54" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource23" type="video/mp4" startat="05:07:54" endat="05:22:53" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource24" type="video/mp4" startat="05:22:53" endat="05:37:52" name="php" description="PHP Video to be played at 5.37">                   
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource25" type="video/mp4" startat="05:37:52" endat="05:52:51" name="PHP Video to be played at 5.37" description="This is PHP Video">                 
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource26" type="video/mp4" startat="05:52:51" endat="06:07:50" name="PHP Video to be played on 5.52" description="PHP Video to be played on 5.52">                    
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource27" type="video/mp4" startat="06:07:50" endat="06:22:49" name="PHP Video to be played on 6.07" description="This is PHP Video">                 
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource28" type="video/mp4" startat="06:22:49" endat="06:37:48" name="PHP Video to be played on 6.22" description="This is PHP Video">                 
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource29" type="video/mp4" startat="06:37:48" endat="06:52:47" name="PHP Video to be played on 6.37" description="This is PHP Video">                 
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource30" type="video/mp4" startat="06:52:47" endat="07:07:46" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource31" type="video/mp4" startat="07:07:46" endat="07:22:45" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource32" type="video/mp4" startat="07:22:45" endat="07:37:44" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource33" type="video/mp4" startat="07:37:44" endat="07:52:43" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource34" type="video/mp4" startat="07:52:43" endat="08:07:42" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource35" type="video/mp4" startat="08:07:42" endat="08:22:41" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource36" type="video/mp4" startat="08:22:41" endat="08:37:40" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource37" type="video/mp4" startat="08:37:40" endat="08:52:39" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource38" type="video/mp4" startat="08:52:39" endat="09:07:38" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                  
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource39" type="video/mp4" startat="09:07:38" endat="09:22:37" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">                          
</video>
```

Java Script

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            var mediaPlayer = document.getElementById('media-video');
             var videosource=document.getElementById('source');
            var Startvideo = mediaPlayer.querySelectorAll('source[startat]');   
            if (mediaPlayer.paused || mediaPlayer.ended) {
                // Change the button to be a pause button
                changeButtonType(playPauseBtn, 'pause');
                // Play the media
                //mediaPlayer.play();
                var d=new Date();       
                var hh=d.getHours();        
                var mm=d.getMinutes();      
                var ss=d.getSeconds();
                var timeString = ((hh < 10) ? "0" : "") + hh;
                timeString  += ((mm < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + mm;
                timeString  += ((ss < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + ss;
                console.log(timeString);        
                var currentTime=timeString;
                console.log('current  time is '+currentTime);       
                Array.prototype.forEach.call(Startvideo, function(elem) {        
                var getStartTime = elem.getAttribute('startat');        
                console.log('start time is '+ getStartTime )                
                     if(getStartTime <= currentTime && elem.getAttribute('endat') >= currentTime){                      
                    var currentTimeSecond=currentTime.split(':');
                    var getStartTimeSecond=getStartTime.split(':');         
                    var TimeSecondsCurrent = (+currentTimeSecond[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+currentTimeSecond[1]) * 60 + (+currentTimeSecond[2]);
                    console.log(TimeSecondsCurrent);
                    var TimeSecondsGetStart= (+getStartTimeSecond[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+getStartTimeSecond[1]) * 60 + (+getStartTimeSecond[2]); 
                    console.log(TimeSecondsGetStart);
                    var totalSeconds= TimeSecondsCurrent - TimeSecondsGetStart;             
                    console.log(totalSeconds);
                    var c=elem.getAttribute('src');         
                    mediaPlayer.src = c;
                    mediaPlayer.currentTime= totalSeconds;  
                    mediaPlayer.play();
                }       
              }); 
            }               
        });
```

Comment: Tell us bit more about _unable to retrieve the next video after the finishing of current video according to current time_

Comment: Suppose current time is 08:56:12. here i got the success to play the video range from 08:50:12 to 08:59:12. but unable to play next video means ranges from 08:59:12 to 09:12:12.

Comment: How do you identify that current video has finished playing ?

Comment: suppose there is event for video like video.addEventListener('ended', function(e){ });

Comment: `mediaPlayer.onended = function() {
        };` will do that for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code to achieve this.

`loadVideo()` reads the `startat` property of the the `source` tag.

These sources are maintained inside a hidden `div`. Once a video ends next one is loaded and written to the `video` tag.

```
<div id="myVideoSources" style="display:none;">
    <source class="active" src="vid1.mp4" id="videoSource" type="video/mp4" startat="00:00:00" endat="00:04:07" name="Something" description="This is Gujarati Videol">
    <source class="active" src="vid2.mp4" id="videosource2" type="video/mp4" startat="00:02:50" endat="00:19:06" name="PHP Video 00:04:07" description="This is PHP Video">
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource3" type="video/mp4" startat="00:19:06" endat="00:34:05" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">
    <source class="active" src="php.mp4" id="videosource4" type="video/mp4" startat="00:34:05" endat="00:49:04" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">
    <source class="active" src="marimatrubhasha.mp4" id="videosource5" type="video/mp4" startat="00:49:04" endat="00:53:11" name="Gujarati Bhasha" description="This is Gujarati Video">
</div>
<video id="media-video" width="600" height="300"></video>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var sources = $("#myVideoSources source");
        var jVideo = $("#media-video");
        var currentVideoNum = 0;
        loadNextVideo();

        jVideo.bind("ended", function () {
            loadNextVideo();
        });

        function loadNextVideo() {
            var source = $(sources.get(currentVideoNum));
            currentVideoNum++;
            if(currentVideoNum >= sources.length) {
                currentVideoNum = 0;
            }

            jVideo.html("");
            jVideo.append(source);
            var plainVideo = jVideo.get(0);
            plainVideo.load();

            plainVideo.play();
            plainVideo.currentTime = getStartTime(source);
        }

        function getStartTime(source) {
            var time = 0;
            try {
                var startAtStr = source.attr("startat");
                time = startAtStr.split(":");
                time = (time[0] * 3600) + (time[1] * 60) + (time[2] * 1)
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
                time = 0;
            }
            return time;
        }
    });
</script>
```